# Return Javascript variable data from external page using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to send a request to a page and grab the entire DOM. Basically a crawl. On this website, there is a variable loaded directly into the HTML (not a script file) with some data. Using my NodeJS backend, which I use [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) with, how would I request this page and return the variable's data? Here's an example:

http://some-page.com/index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var my_var = {
                title: "Good title",
                description: "Nice description",
                page: 5
            };
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

If I visit the website, open the console and type in `my_var` I can see the content in the console, so it's a global variable.

How can I do something like this? I can use another request library if that is needed.

Comment: Perhaps in the response callback, something to the effect of `eval(body.match(/<script>.*<\/script>/).join('\n'))` where body is the third parameter of the callback (per the example in the repo's readme).

Comment: Use the npm module Cheerio.

Comment: @wilusdaman So executing all the JS on the page into the Node backend? Surely there's a better way.

Comment: @DanielZuzevich Cheerio cannot do this, as far as I know.

Comment: @MortenMoulder there surely is. Just wanted to give what's probably the simplest solution (and ignore the horrendous security implications of that approach)

Comment: @wilusdaman That's exactly one of my concerns. Also not knowing where the script tag is on the page, makes this a bit more tricky as well.

Comment: What are the security implications of that? Just curious. Really asking, not being sarcastic.

Comment: @DanielZuzevich The other website can easily run JavaScript code inside my environment, if I decide to execute their code.

Comment: Oh my bad, I thought you were talking about Cheerio.

Comment: @DanielZuzevich Oh nope, I love Cheerio haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for jsdom: https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom

```
const dom = new JSDOM(`<body>
  <script>document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("hr"));</script>
</body>`, { runScripts: "dangerously" });

// The script will be executed and modify the DOM:
dom.window.document.body.children.length === 2;
```

it also come with a Virtual Console

> Virtual consoles
>
> Like web browsers, jsdom has the concept of a "console". This records
>   both information directly sent from the page, via scripts executing
>   inside the document, as well as information from the jsdom
>   implementation itself.

Comment: In my example, how would I enter the URL of the website and extract the data from the known variable?

Comment: you get the content of the page and put it in the jsdom to execute it. maybe add code in there to console log to the virtual console and get the output.

Comment: Ah okay, it seems a bit "dangerous" (hence the `runScripts: "dangerously"`) to run unknown code on my backend. I guess it works, though. Thanks!

Comment: There are security guidelines on the  jsdom github page. I am not sure about your exact use case, but I recommended jsdom because say the script is manipulating DOM, putting the output in a div or something you can get the that in the jsdom.